# Running a Java Project without using IDE or CommandPrompt

Tags: java

I've made a quiz consisting of multiple jFrames and connectivity to a MySQL table. I need to know how to get it in a form that I can put on a CD as a soft copy for a demonstration at school, since this is a project. My teacher isn't able to help me and I checked all the books I have... please help!

Comment: If the MySQL DB is installed locally, then make sure a copy is installed on your presentation machine.  Everything else, you can use a JAR for.

Comment: Welcome to the horrid world of distribution.

Comment: What IDE are you using? Netbeans stores a jar in the dist folder, and with eclipse its a matter of exporting the project to runnable jar file. Then double clicking should do the job..

Answer (score 1):

Build up an [executable jar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/jar/jarGuide.html) out of your project, have a JRE on target machine and execute jar file to demonstrate your project without IDE

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at [PortableApps.com](http://PortableApps.com).  You can build a memory stick with a JRE and there is a util to run Jars.  This way you will not have to install anything on the host machine.  You can even go so far as to install Portable Eclipse on the stick for last minute changes or to debug any problems you may find.

Answer (score 0):

Take a copy of your executable JAR file, MYSQL and JRE installable software's into the CD. Install MySQL and JRE on your demonstration machine before executing your JAR.